# Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC Issues

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader

I have a question about the two programs that I have at work. We have both programs Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC. Both have the same Version 2017.009.20044. So, on my computer I have Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and some other employees might have Adobe Acrobat Reader DC on their computer.

So when I export my map to PDF, and send it to someone and they open the map with the Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, they say they see strange looking symbols all over the map. For example, there are some symbols that show J which are not supposed to show up on the map.

My question here: is there a way for me to fix or change the settings to prevent them from seeing their PDF haywire? I am not sure how that works but I have ArcGIS 10.3.1. The ArcGIS 10.3.1 has its own PDF and I can set the settings but I'm not sure how. We plan on to get upgrade to ArcGIS 10.5 anytime.

Here is the example : [image]

Comment: This looks like it might be an issue with fonts you have on each computer. Can you check the list of fonts in the document? Maybe you can embed the fonts, if you haven't.

Comment: Hey Never Mind, I just solved the problem. It has nothing to do with the programs I mention. It is the ArcGIS 10.3.1. software. My "Embed All Documents Fonts" was off . So, I enabled that one back on and had someone open the PDF again and that one worked.